# Ionic2 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'ion-item-content' is not a known element: error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my code from `movie-info.html`:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Movie Info
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="home" padding>
  <div *ngIf="movie" class="selection">
    <ion-card>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <img src="path/to/image{{movie-poster}}"/>
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-item-content class="movie-title-data">
                <h1>{{movie.title}}</h1>
                <p>{{movie.release_date}}</p>
            </ion-item-content>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <icon document item-left></icon>
            <h2>Overview</h2>
            <p class="item-description">{{movie.overview}}</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <icon bookmark item-left></icon>
            <h2>Average Vote</h2>
            <p>{{movie.vote_average}}</p>
        </ion-item>    
    </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ion-item-content' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-item-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-item-content' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("path/to/image{{movie-poster}}"/>
            </ion-avatar>
            [ERROR ->]<ion-item-content class="movie-title-data">
                <h1>{{movie.title}}</h1>
        "): MovieInfoPage@15:16

'icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Similar error keeps going on for all elements.

This is `movie-info.ts`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'movie-info.html'
})

export class MovieInfoPage {

  movie: {};  

  constructor(private navController: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {
    this.movie = navParams.get('movie');
  }   
}
```

Comment: So your `MovieListPage` doesn't have a selector?

Comment: @echonax I don't know what you mean by that. This is the very first time I am using Ionic2. :)

Comment: Inside your `@Component` annotation where `templateUrl` and `providers` is, you need to have a `selector` to reference the component as an element. But I don't know much about ionic, it might be different. What's the relation between `MovieInfoPage` and `MovieListPage`?

Comment: I think Ionic uses `entryComponents` for that purpose. I had specified it in the Movie List Page but that gave me the error `Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'ion-item-content' is not a known element:.`

Comment: @echonax Movie List has a list of movies and clicking on any of them takes us to the MovieInfo Page.

Comment: Can you share the html of ListPage and ts of InfoPage please?

Comment: @echonax I am sorry for the delay. I have added the code. :)

Comment: you are not using scss at all ? for selectors...

Comment: @suraj I am following [this tutorial](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-tutorial-lets-create-our-first-application/). I made some changes to file names because of the difference in Ionic version.

Comment: are you using ionic beta?

Comment: @suraj Typing `ionic -v` shows the version as 2.0.0.

Comment: what is the version of `ionic-angular` in package.json?

Comment: @suraj the version is 2.0.0-rc.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the template error:

As it suggests `ion-item-content` is not a valid tag in ionic 2.
I suggest using a div instead.

[ion-item component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/item/Item/)

Comment: Actually, the filename is `movie-info.ts`. I made a mistake in the question.

Comment: ok.. now you are getting 'No component factory found for ' or parse error?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion Suraj. I am editing the question to be more clear. I misunderstood the error I was getting. Sorry.

Comment: can you also add movie-info.html?

Comment: I have added the files.